# Displaying the item that is after and before in ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I did :

```
<li ng-repeat="card in cards" ng-if="list._id == card.list">{{card.name}} 
<button ng-click="take($index)">HERE</button>{{ $index}}</li>
```

[image]

And I have question:

If I displayed items from the board by ng-repeat also ng-if, how can i do that after click Here will be displayed console.log() with name before item and after??

In blackboard There are mixed cards for different lists.

Comment: Where is the code for the function `take($index)`, you can just do a `console.log()` at the start and end of the function I guess, can you please share the JS code for the function, if possible a little bit more HTML.

Comment: Ok here is html + angularJS https://jsfiddle.net/820o2j7q/

Comment: some more clarification,  what do you need to happen inside `take($index)` also please clarify the line `displayed console.log() name before item and after`

Comment: for example : I want do, that, when u click on first column on second. Console log will display (first, third)

Comment: I tried replicating the lists, but its very confusing since you are having three lists `cards`, `tasks`, `lists` so its difficult to understand what is actually going on. Can you provide the lists sample data and give me a basic working complete example, so that I can work on getting the output, here is a fiddle with what I was trying [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8khb4q7/), You need to take the $index, and check each of the lists under `$scope.lists` and `console.log` the output I guess!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of the special properties `$index`, `$first` and `$last` to determine which cards are before and after the selected card in your `take()` function.

Pass those additional properties in your `ng-click` directive on the button:

```
<button ng-click="take($index, $first, $last)">HERE</button>{{ $index}}</li>
```

And update your controller's `take()` function:

```
$scope.take = function(index, first, last){
  if (!first) console.log(cards[index-1].name);
  if (!last) console.log(cards[index+1].name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Almost there, the only problem is that if I add one card to the first list and then 3 cards to the list number 3 and back to add the card to the first list it will show you the card of 3 letters because I show it in the table not in the list.

Comment: @BartłomiejFlis I don't understand sorry, is there still an outstanding issue? Maybe it should be another question or is it directly related to what's goin on here?